# what is the effect of non modifiable data in HDFS on the HDFS architecture?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i have been searching alot about HDFS, but i didnt find an answer to my question, can anyone help me please.

what is the effect of non modifiable data in HDFS on the HDFS architecture?

Comment: What is non-modifiable data and why would it affect the architecture?

Comment: HDFS is based on _Write once, read multiple times_, if that 's what you are referring to.

Comment: yes thats what i meant, the write once .. is that affect the architecture of HDFS?

Comment: can you help me please ?